# Talend Force run order of joblets

Tags: talend

My company has a couple of joblets that we put in new jobs to do things like initialization of variables, get system information from the database and sending out error / warning emails. The issue we are running into is that if we go ahead and start creating the components of a job and realize that we forgot to include these 3 joblets, we have to basically re-create the job to ensure that the joblets are added first so they run first.

Is there any way to force these joblets to run first and possibly also in a certain order before moving on to the contents of the job being created? Please let me know if there is any information you may need that I'm missing as I have only been using Talend for a few days. The rest of the team has not been using it too much longer than I have, so they do not have the answer I'm looking for either. Thanks in advance!

Comment: there is tPrejob which you can use to and connect your joblets one after another to this..this should run first, OR you can drop you joblets and connect them via onSubJob/componentOK trigger to next components in your job and that way your dependency would be maintained..

Comment: @garpitmzn thank you for the response, but I am having an issue where the only option I have from tprejob is "on component ok", and that does not let me connect to any of the joblets I have in the project. Note: this is regardless of whether or not the joblets are marked as "startable".

Comment: ok then can you ignore tprejob and simply do joblet1--->onsubjjobOK-->joblet2-->onsubjobOK-->joblet3-->your job first component...this way your job will always start from joblet1

Answer (score 0):

In Joblets you can use the components `Trigger_Input` and `Trigger_Output` as connection-points for `on subjob OK` triggers. So you can connect joblets and other components in a job with triggers. Thus enforcing execution order.

But you cannot get a on subjob OK trigger from a tPreJob. I am thinking on triggering from a `tPreJob` to a `tWarn` (on component OK) and then from tWarn to the joblet (on subjob OK).